# Wrapping a functions taking a variable number of arguments using a decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

I want to create a decorator which can wrap around functions with different numbers of variables. For example, below I have two functions `abc` and `abcd`, taking 2 and 3 arguments respectively. I want the wrapper to take a variable number of arguments in order to deal with this. However, when I run the code, I get `TypeError: _wrapper() takes exactly 0 arguments (2 given)`, as though the `**kwargs` was ignored.

Why is this, and how do I fix this?

```
def dec(function):
    def _wrapper(**kwargs):
        print len(kwargs)
        function(**kwargs)
    return _wrapper

@dec
def abc(a, b):
    return a*b

@dec
def abcd(a, b, c):
    return a*b*c
```

Comment: In part you probably want to use [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python has two variable argument variables: `*args` and `**kwargs`. `args` is a list of arguments specified without names (e.g. `func(1,2,3)`), while `kwargs` is a dictionary of arguments with names (e.g. `func(x=1, y=2, z=3)`).

Your code is only accepting the kwargs, so you also need to add the unnamed args:

```
def dec(function):
    def _wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print len(args) + len(kwargs)
        return function(*args, **kwargs)
    return _wrapper
```

Comment: Ah yes of course, many thanks. I made this error because I also would like to know the names of the function parameters inside _wrapper. Is there any way to find out the name of the nth parameter of the function that is being wrapped?